# List out of bounds

Tags: python-3.x

```
def f(x,t):
    return x

t = np.linspace(3, 5, 7)
x = np.zeros(7)
h = 1
i = 0

while i <= len(t):
   x[0] = 0
   x[i+1] = x[i] + h*  f(x[i], t[i]) 
   i += 1
```

but I keep getting index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

In Python the indices start at 0 not 1. So if you want to iterate over the array, you have to iterate over the interval **[0, len(list)-1]**

Your while loop contains `<=` and also contains the index 7 because `len(t)` returns 7 in your case.

Plus in the while loop, you are computing the value at the next index i+1 depending on the previous value. So, when you arrive at the very last index, you are trying to compute the value at index 7 based on index 6. However, the index 7 does not exist. You are basically done at len(list) - 2

Just replace it to `while i < len(t)-1`. You would iterate till the index 5 and compute the value for index 6 which is the last index of your list